# Порт завершения ввод-вывода и обрыв связи или закрытие сокета

Tags: winapi, winsock, winsock2

Подскажите, вот такая вот "проблема":

Предположим вот есть вот такая вот ситуация:

- Создал сокет
- Связал его спортом завершения
- Соединился с удаленным сервером WSACOnnect
- Вызвал WSASend для отправки данных на сервер и помещение задачи

отправки в очередь порта завершения.

Предположим я отправляю 10Гб данных на сервер. В какой то момент происходит следующее:

- происходит обрыв связи у какой то из сторон.
- обрыва связи не происходит, но удаленный сервер по какой то причине закрывает сокет.

И вот вопрос: получается задача на отправку так и останется в очереди порта завершения пока не выполнится ?
Если со случаем обрыва связи - при возвращении связи задача в итоге будет завершена и грубо говоря я буду оповещен о том, что задача отправки готова и ее можно забрать из очереди порта завершения.

То в случае с закрытием сокета на удаленном сервере, задача так навсегда и останется в порут завершения ?

Как такие случаи должны обрабатываться ?

Answer (score 0):

Чтоб происходит при разных сценариях зависит от используемых протоколов. Передача любых данных по сети происходит на нескольких уровнях (подробнее: [https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Сетевая_модель_OSI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI)).

Если сильно упростить, то при передаче могут происходить следующие проблемы:

1. **потеряется очередной пакет данных**. В случае протокола TCP эта потеря будет обнаружена и пакет будет передан повторно, получатель не заметит ничего кроме некоторой задержки. В случае протокола UDP эти данные просто не дойдут до получателя, он получит не всё что ему отправил отправитель.
2. **одна из сторон закроет сокет**. В этом случае другая сторона будет уведомлена о разрыве соединения специальным паетом и тоже закроет свой сокет.
3. **пропадет связь и данные совсем перестанут ходить**. В этом случае через заданное время сработает таймер и соединение на обоих сторонах будет закрыто по таймауту. Время таймаута можно настроить.

Так что ничего не зависнет, отправка в случаях 2 и 3 вернет вам ошибку, которую вы сможете обработать и понять что произошло.

**Дополнение:** Конкретно по случаю WSASend - результат операции отправки передается в качестве параметра в callback, задаваемый последним параметром в вызове WSASend: *lpCompletionRoutine*

```
int WSAAPI WSASend(
  SOCKET                             s,
  LPWSABUF                           lpBuffers,
  DWORD                              dwBufferCount,
  LPDWORD                            lpNumberOfBytesSent,
  DWORD                              dwFlags,
  LPWSAOVERLAPPED                    lpOverlapped,
  LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE lpCompletionRoutine
);
```

Этот callback имеет тип [LPWSAOVERLAPPED_COMPLETION_ROUTINE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nc-winsock2-lpwsaoverlapped_completion_routine):

```
void LpwsaoverlappedCompletionRoutine(
  DWORD dwError,
  DWORD cbTransferred,
  LPWSAOVERLAPPED lpOverlapped,
  DWORD dwFlags
)
```

где *dwErrorCode* - код результата передачи. При удачной отправке там будет 0 (ERROR_SUCCESS)

*dwNumberOfBytesTransfered* - число переданных байт. В случае ошибки - 0

Comment: спасибо, но вопрос был немного в другом конечно. Вопрос в том, что сама задача в очереди порта завершения никуда не денется и будет получается там находится вечно ? Порт завершения меня же ника не уведомит о том, что удаленный сервер закрыл сокет или что пропала связь.

Comment: По идее должен уведомить об ошибке. Прийдёт сокетовская ошибка из разряда 12ххх (socket errors)

Comment: @nick_n_a, так откуда она 'эта ошибка придет и куда, если задача в очереди порта завершения ? Сам WSASend - завершился успешно, и ошибок нет. Связь разрывается или сокет закрывается условно на середине передаче, а передачей уже занимается Completion ports.

Comment: @Optimus1 добавил в ответ описание по получению результата отправки конкретно для WSASend. Он приходит в качестве параметра в callback в момент завершения операции, в том числе при её прерывании.

Comment: @Alexander Ushakov, еще раз Спасибо, но, я использую, как и написано в описании порт завершения ввода вывода Windows и не использую callback lpCompletionRoutine.

Comment: @Optimus1 Пожалуйста, указывайте названия функций, которые используете - это упрощает понимание. Раз вы используете `I/O completion ports` (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/i-o-completion-ports), то для получения результатов отправки есть функция `GetQueuedCompletionStatus` https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/ioapiset/nf-ioapiset-getqueuedcompletionstatus

Comment: @Alexander Ushakov, я это знаю, спасибо за напоминание.

Comment: @Optimus1 Хм, если известно, тогда в чем собственно вопрос?

Comment: @Alexander Ushakov, в том, что GetQueuedCompletionStatus - не возвращает ошибки. То есть я помещаю задачу в очередь завершения, вытыкаю сетевой шнур, но ошибки нет. А задача в очереди порта завершения есть.